# /usr/bin/ No such file or directory after mount --rbind

Tags: bash, shell, mount

I don't know why `mount` caused some files in `/usr/bi`n to be removed. It's made everything out of control:

[image: it happened after mount --rbind /dev /home/binex]

I also trying `umount` but it says `-bash: umount: command not found`

What can I do to recover this thing? I can't `ls`, `cat`, but I can `cd` to any dir, and also I can use `TAB` in any place to display all things, and I don't know why everything is showing up here:

[image: help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't ask you why do you do this, but I can explain this issue.

When you mount `/bin` to `/home/binex` then you have `/bin` directory in `/home/binex` too and from file system point it's the same directories. Next, when you mount `/dev` to `/home/binex` you definitely mount `/dev` to `/bin`, because `/home/binex` and `/bin` mount points (after first `mount` command) is equal mount points and they point to one directory. Therefore you overlap your `/bin` and can't access to `mount` command.

So, files are not being removed. They are being overlapped. Reboot will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, this is a consequence of *mount propagation*.

Modern systems, including anything which boots with `systemd`, enable mount propagation on `/` and child mounts by default.  It is recommended generally, for the benefit of mount namespaces.

This means that when you create a bind mount, by default any mount operations you make underneath the bind mount are also applied to the source directory.  (More usefully, the propagation also works the other way round).

If you have the misfortune to not know about this and end up over-mounting `/bin` (which I'm guessing is a symlink to `/usr/bin`) with something else, you won't be able to access your normal commands.  Ouch.

If you want to find out a bit more about the effect of mount propagation, you could start by skimming through `man mount`.  It references some other documents as well.